# How do I automatically start cron on docker alpine?

Tags: docker, cron, alpine-linux

I am trying to run cron jobs on an alpine-based image (node:18.6.0-alpine3.15 to be exact).

The relevant lines of my Dockerfile are as follows:

```
FROM node:18.6.0-alpine3.15
RUN apk add--update busybox-suid
COPY ./config/crontab.txt /etc/crontabs/root
```

When I run this image, cron does not automatically start. If I run `crond restart` as root in the container, however, it starts running as expected.

I would like to automatically start the cron daemon on startup of the container.
What is the recommended way of doing so?

I googled around a bit and found this:

[https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux:FAQ#Why_don't_my_cron_jobs_run](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux:FAQ#Why_don%27t_my_cron_jobs_run)?

However, this did not solve my issue and cron still did not start up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There are no background processes in a container, so `crond` isn't running.

To start it, add

```
CMD crond -f
```

at the end of your Dockerfile. That will make `crond` run in the foreground.

Comment: I want to run crond in the background, is that possible? I am using the image to run a node.js server, and would like to run that on startup instead. I am also using the "node" user within the image.

Comment: Just remove the -f